# How to higlight the TabControl Tab Page on moving mouse pointer in windows form?

Tags: c#, highlight, tabcontrol, windows-forms-designer, tabpage

I've found a solution for changing the back color but nothing helps me with tab highlight.
Also, I don't understand what this code is doing:

```
private void tcSupportApp_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle mouseRect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 1, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < tcSupportApp.TabCount; i++)
    {
        if (tcSupportApp.GetTabRect(i).Contains(e.Location))
        {
            if (tcSupportApp.SelectedIndex != i)
            {
                tcSupportApp.SelectedIndex = i;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code selects/opens each tab upon moving over it. If you only want to highlight it use Ajit's answer which changes the selected tab text to bold. You may want to combine both.

Comment: That code is executed when the Mouse pointer moves on a `TabControl` header. It then iterates all of the `TabControl` headers and checks on which header area (Rectangle) the Mouse pointer is moving (`.GetTabRect(i).Contains(e.Location))`) <= this uses the `Rectangle.Contains(Point)` method. If the Mouse is moving over the header of a `TabPage` which is not the currently selected one, it selects it (a `break;` is missing after `tcSupportApp.SelectedIndex = i;`). This allows to select a `TabPage` just moving the Mouse pointer over a header, without clicking it. `Rectangle mouseRec` is not used.

Comment: Thanks, @TaW for the explanation. It does help.

Comment: Thanks, @Jimi for such an elaborate explanation. That clears the first part of my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to to below tasks :

1. Change DrawMode property to OwnerDrawFixed
2. Add tcSupportApp_DrawItem event handler to this control with below code

```
private void tcSupportApp_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    TabPage SelectedTab = tcSupportApp.TabPages[e.Index];
    Rectangle HeaderRect = tcSupportApp.GetTabRect(e.Index);
    SolidBrush TextBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
    {
        Font BoldFont = new Font(tcSupportApp.Font.Name, tcSupportApp.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(SelectedTab.Text, BoldFont, TextBrush, HeaderRect, sf);
    }
    else
        e.Graphics.DrawString(SelectedTab.Text, e.Font, TextBrush, HeaderRect, sf);
    TextBrush.Dispose();
}
```

Credits : http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2014/09/14/windows-forms-how-to-bold-the-header-of-a-selected-tab.aspx

Comment: Hello Ajit, Thanks for responding but the above code is for the background color. I just want to highlight the tab page on mouse hover- consider there are 5 pages , so on moving the mouse on the tab page it should get highlighted(hot track)

Comment: Try with `e.DrawBackground();` Insert it as the first line of code. The rendering of the text section can be improved with `e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;` and using a ClearType font (SegoeUI, for example).

Comment: Hello Dipanwita , Why don't you just give it a try the sample code I provided. It highlights the tab header rectangle area. For making it highlighted code makes text bold, you can modify this behavior as per your needs.

Comment: Hi Ajit, I have tried the code that you've suggested but it doesn't suit my requirement. I was hoping to highlight the tab page on mouse hover similar to how it works with buttons. Is that possible by any means?

Comment: Hi Jimi, Thanks for the suggestion. But adding e.DrawBackground(); is giving the background color on click, which I don't want. Anything that would help in higlighing the tab page like how it does for a button on mouse hover would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dipanwita Biswas  The modifications I proposed are related to the code that @Ajit posted. You have to combine this answer with your original code and use both events (`MouseMove` and `DrawItem`).

Comment: Hi @Ajit  can you suggest anything for changing the color of the tab page on mouse hover rather than bold text?

Comment: Hi @DipanwitaBiswas you can get help from below article

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8289/Coloring-Tab-Control

Answer (score 0):

If you create a custom tabControl derived from tab control this can be handled via OnPaintBackground. In this code snippet the inactive tabs will be painted with a blue highlight when hovered.

**Derive from TabControl**

```
public partial class MyTabControl : TabControl
{
...
```

**Set style for user paint**

```
public MyTabControl()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  //set style for user controlled painting
  this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | 
                ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
...
```

**While painting tabs check for current mouse position over inactive tabs**

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
  using (SolidBrush backBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(250, 250, 250)))
  {
    Graphics g = pevent.Graphics;
    g.FillRectangle(backBrush, 0, 0, this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height); //paint background

    foreach (TabPage tp in this.TabPages)
    {
      int index = this.TabPages.IndexOf(tp);
      this.TabBoundary = this.GetTabRect(index);
      this.TabTextBoundary = (RectangleF)this.GetTabRect(index);
      bool isTabHover = false;

      if (this.TabBoundary.Contains(this.PointToClient(MousePosition)))
      {
        isTabHover = true;
      }
      if (tp == SelectedTab)
      {
        //paint active tab
        g.FillRectangle(backBrush, this.TabBoundary);
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, this.TabBoundary.X, this.TabBoundary.Y, this.TabBoundary.Width, 2);
        g.DrawString(tp.Text, _activeTabFont, Brushes.Black, this.TabTextBoundary, _tabStringFormat);
      }
      else
      {
        //paint inactive tab
        if (isTabHover)
        {
          g.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightBlue, this.TabBoundary)
        }
        else
        {
          g.FillRectangle(backBrush, this.TabBoundary);
        }
        g.DrawString(tp.Text, _inactiveTabFont, Brushes.Black, this.TabTextBoundary, _tabStringFormat);
      }
    }
  }
}
```